# Package 'netplan' has no installation candidate

Tags: server, netplan

I'm having issues with installing netplan in Ubuntu Server. I keep getting the error message "Package 'netplan' has no installation candidate. How would I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The correct name of the package is `netplan.io`

Answer (score 3):

Try this and see if you find it more than likely missing the .io on the end in the package name.

```
root@zeus-H370M-DS3H:~# apt-cache search netplan
libnetplan-dev - Development files for netplan's libnetplan runtime library
libnetplan0 - YAML network configuration abstraction runtime library
netplan.io - YAML network configuration abstraction for various backends
```

Comment: I used the command given and I see that .io is present.